# How does one trigger matplotlib to initialize the cache on install in an image?

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib

When installing `matplotlib` there is a significant cost to first time use when running an image in single-threaded mode described by the following message:

```
Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment.
```

Note that this first time cost applies every time when running from a docker image.  This makes it an exponential cost in a business application, and it must be fixed.  This means that a matplotlib dependency in an image requires an elaboration on the installation concept, discussed next.

---

Optionally, in the docker file, I can trigger the cache build by importing the library:

```
RUN python -c "import matplotlib; # etc."
```

As part of the `matplotlib` install, but **IDEALLY** an install is an install, and doesn't bleed into other components like glue or gum (very applied-science/handy-crafty rather than engineered).

I can see how **"normally"** this is not a problem, and re-paradigm-ing is a way to get things done. But we call installation "installation" for a reason and violating the boundaries of plumbing concepts in plumbing applications is ultimately going to be problematic.

---

How does one build the font cache upon installation so that my docker image is more performant upon startup?

Comment: Shooting in the dark -- is it possible to copy over a local font cache into the docker image when you build it?

Comment: @PaulH It is worth trying.  Although, if possible, can it be distributed?